# Mapping Profile Attributes to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Is it necessary to map Marketing Cloud profile attributes with Salesforce when we are only going to be bringing in data from salesforce through marketing cloud connect? Since the data is being stored in synchronized data extensions can't we just filter off of those data extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don’t need to do that at all.

Profile attributes are tied to the All Subscribers list and don’t give you the flexibility that you will have when using Data Extensions, so I’d stick to using Synchronized DEs only. And yes, you can filter them any way you wish.

Comment: Do we need to map profile attributes if we want the customer to be able to see these salesforce attributes on their profile center? or is there a way to populate a profile center from a synchronized DE

Comment: If you want to use the standard profile center then yes you need to map them, but for a better, scalable solution I would advise building a custom preference center: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/01/14/custom-profile-and-subscription-center-integrated-with-sales-service-cloud/